# Match one row to two rows without replacement

Tags: sql, replace, conditional-statements, match, teradata

I want to match each person who submits an order (`YES`) with two people who did not submit an order (`NO`) and have the same `gender` and `age`.  If a person matches with person `x`, `x` cannot be paired with anyone else.  And if person `x` has a `contact_date`, it must be larger than the `order_date` of its original match.

```
ID  Gender  AGE  ORDER  ORDER_DATE    CONTACT_DATE
1    M      18   YES    10/10/2019    Nan
2    F      25   NO     Nan           09/06/2016 
3    M      54   YES    08/04/2018    09/08/2018
4    M      30   YES    09/11/2016    12/ 12/2016
```

I managed to select two IDs from the people who did not order and matched them with one person who did order. But I do not know how to include the condition "if a person who did not order has a `contact_date`, it should be larger than the `order_date` of its match"

```sql
CREATE TABLE 1st_match AS (
  SELECT b*.
  FROM (
    SELECT aa.*, ROW NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, GENDER ORDER BY ID1 ASC) rn
    FROM (diag_orderedcostumer aa) a,
    SELECT bb.*, ROW NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, GENDER ORDER BY ID2 ASC) rn
    FROM (diag_notorderedcostumer bb) b
    WHERE a.gender = b.gender 
    AND a.rn = b.rn 
    AND a.AGE = b.AGE
) WITH DATA;

CREATE TABLE 2nd_match AS (
  SELECT b*.
  FROM ( 
    SEL aa.*, ROW NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, GENDER ORDER BY ID1 ASC) rn
    FROM (diag_orderedcostumer aa) a,
    SEL bb.*, ROW NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, GENDER ORDER BY ID2 ASC) rn
    FROM (diag_notorderedcostumer bb
    WHERE ID2 NOT IN (SEL DISTINCT ID2 FROM 1st_match)
  ) b
  WHERE a.gender = b.gender 
  AND a.rn = b.rn 
  AND a.AGE = b.AGE
) WITH DATA;

CREATE TABLE control final AS (
  SELECT * FROM 1st_match UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM 2nd_match
) WITH DATA;
```

```
ID  ID2  ID3   Gender AGE ORDER_DATE  cont_date1   cont_date1  cont_date1
1   30   106   M      18  10/10/2019  Nan          11/12/3019  nan
3   400  1700  M      54  08/04/2018  09/08/2018   nan         09/12/2019
4   256  865   M      30  09/11/2016  12/ 12/2016  1/1/2017    05/12/2018
```

Comment: I am so confused reading this.  I don't get what you really want to do.

Comment: This query doesn't look properly formatted - `b*.` should be `b.*`?  And there appear to be unclosed parentheses too.  Does it execute as posted?  If you want to add extra conditional logic for your join, you can try something like this: `AND (contact_date > order_date OR contact_date IS NULL)`